# Function-local struct breaks Visual Studio's STL debug visualizers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, stl, debuggervisualizer

When the struct/class is outside the function:

```
#include <vector>
struct Foo { };
int main()
{
    std::vector< Foo > foos;
    return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2012's STL debug visualizer handles `foos` just fine:

```
Name                    Value               Type
-       foos            { size=0 }          std::vector<Foo,std::allocator<Foo> >
            [size]      0                   int
            [capacity]  0                   int
    +       [Raw View]  0x0026fbcc {...}    std::vector<Foo,std::allocator<Foo> > *
```

But when `Foo` is inside `main()`:

```
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    struct Foo { };
    std::vector< Foo > foos;
    return 0;
}
```

The debugger spits back garbage(?) types/values that look like name mangling gone horribly wrong:

```
Name                                                                                                            Value                                                                           Type
-       foos                                                                                                    {...}                                                                           std::?$vector@UFoo@?1?main@V?$allocator@UFoo@?1?main@@std@@
    -       std::?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@UFoo@?1?main@V?$allocator@UFoo@?1?main@@std@@@std@@     {...}                                                                           std::?$_Vector_alloc@$0A@U?$_Vec_base_types@UFoo@?1?main@V?$allocator@UFoo@?1?main@@std@@@std@@
        -       std::?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@UFoo@?1?main@@std@@                                         {_Myfirst=0x00000000 {...}  _Mylast=0x00000000 {...} _Myend=0x00000000 {...} }  std::?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@UFoo@?1?main@@std@@
                    std::_Container_base0                                                                       {...}                                                                           std::_Container_base0
                    _Myfirst                                                                                    0x00000000 {...}                                                                main::__l2::Foo *
                    _Mylast                                                                                     0x00000000 {...}                                                                main::__l2::Foo *
                    _Myend                                                                                      0x00000000 {...}                                                                main::__l2::Foo *
```

Two questions:

- What's going on here?
- Any fixes/workarounds? (...other than the obvious "move `Foo` outside `main()`")